# Conditionally add fields to steps in backstage scaffolder template

Tags: yaml, nunjucks, backstage

how can I add optional fields to a step based on if user has provided an input parameter? I'm not looking for an entire step to be skipped but only one parameter.

In the following example, I want to add `collaborators` section in the `publish:github` step only if the user has selected an additional collaborator from the parameter section.

```yaml
apiVersion: scaffolder.backstage.io/v1beta3
# https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-catalog/descriptor-format#kind-template
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: example-nodejs-template
  title: Example Node.js Template
  description: An example template for the scaffolder that creates a simple Node.js service
spec:
  owner: user:guest
  type: service

  # These parameters are used to generate the input form in the frontend, and are
  # used to gather input data for the execution of the template.
  parameters:
    - title: Fill in some steps
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          title: Name
          type: string
          description: Unique name of the component
          ui:autofocus: true
          ui:options:
            rows: 5
        collaborators:
          title: Additional collaborators
          type: string
          description: Github team
          ui:field: EntityPicker
          ui:options:
            orderable: false
            catalogFilter:
              - kind: [Group]
                metadata.annotations.github.com/team-slug: { exists: true }

  # These steps are executed in the scaffolder backend, using data that we gathered
  # via the parameters above.
  steps:

    # Each step executes an action, in this case one templates files into the working directory.
    - id: fetch-base
      name: Fetch Base
      action: fetch:template
      input:
        url: ./content
        values:
          name: ${{ parameters.name }}

    # This step publishes the contents of the working directory to GitHub.
    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:github
      input:
        allowedHosts: ["github.com"]
        description: This is the ${{ parameters.name }}.
        repoUrl: github.com?repo=${{ parameters.name }}&owner=manuviswam
        defaultBranch: main
        collaborators:
          - team: ${{ parameters.collaborators }}
            access: admin

    # The final step is to register our new component in the catalog.
    - id: register
      name: Register
      action: catalog:register
      input:
        repoContentsUrl: ${{ steps['publish'].output.repoContentsUrl }}
        catalogInfoPath: '/catalog-info.yaml'

  # Outputs are displayed to the user after a successful execution of the template.
  output:
    links:
      - title: Repository
        url: ${{ steps['publish'].output.remoteUrl }}
      - title: Open in catalog
        icon: catalog
        entityRef: ${{ steps['register'].output.entityRef }}
```

I've tried to use Nunjucks if condition as follows but it gives me a YAML parsing error

```yaml
    - id: publish
      name: Publish
      action: publish:github
      input:
        allowedHosts: ["github.com"]
        description: This is the ${{ parameters.name }}.
        repoUrl: github.com?repo=${{ parameters.name }}&owner=manuviswam
        defaultBranch: main
        {% if parameters.collaborators %}
        collaborators:
          - team: ${{ parameters.collaborators }}
            access: admin
        {% endif %}
```

Comment: I dont think so conditionally render fields are allowed in scaffolder.
We also faced this scenario where we wanted to hide the field, so for time being achieved with vanilla js and css.

Answer (score 0):

Using Nunjucks in scaffolder template is actually in backstage backlog: https://github.com/backstage/backstage/issues/16275

Some alternative for conditional steps is to use oneOf: https://github.com/JamesAtIntegratnIO/backstage-templates/blob/50c05ce95ad07ff2b49b9526b5a5c1e94acee7b7/kubernetes-basic-app/template.yaml#L124

```yaml
options:
  pickOption:
    title: Options
    type: string
    default: option1
    enum:
      - option1
      - option2
      - option3
      - option4
dependencies:
  pickOption:
    oneOf:
      - options:
          pickOption:
            enum:
              - option1
              - option2
          foo:
            title: foo
            type: string
          bar:
            title: bar
            type: string
      - options:
          pickOption:
            enum:
              - option3
          fooBar:
            title: foobar
            type: string
      - options:
          pickOption:
            enum:
              - option4
```

Backstage Schema is tranlated to react-jsonschema. A schema with oneOf is valid if exactly one of the subschemas is valid.
https://rjsf-team.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/docs/usage/oneof/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35112875)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the new [conditional logic](https://backstage.io/docs/features/software-templates/input-examples#use-parameters-as-condition-in-steps) that was just added to accomplish this? Something like this:

```
    - id: publish
      name: Publish with collaborators
      if: ${{ parameters.collaborators != null }}
      action: publish:github
      input:
        allowedHosts: ["github.com"]
        description: This is the ${{ parameters.name }}.
        repoUrl: github.com?repo=${{ parameters.name }}&owner=manuviswam
        defaultBranch: main
        collaborators:
          - team: ${{ parameters.collaborators }}
            access: admin

    - id: publish
      name: Publish without collaborators 
      if: ${{ parameters.collaborators == null }}
      action: publish:github
      input:
        allowedHosts: ["github.com"]
        description: This is the ${{ parameters.name }}.
        repoUrl: github.com?repo=${{ parameters.name }}&owner=manuviswam
        defaultBranch: main
```

Then in the wizard, only the Publish that was run will have a check above it.